# Blender border render internals

Tags: rendering, render, blender

I would like to know how Blender's border render works internally. How can Blender compute lights if it has not information about the lights in the tiles he won't render? I have not found any reference (source code excluded) on how this feature of blender works. Can somebody explain it (or give me some reference)?

Answer (score 0):

The render border setting only alters what part of the image is rendered, it does not alter what data is sent to the render engine to generate the image.

You can test this by placing an object with a reflective surface in front of the camera and another object behind the camera, the object behind the camera will show in the reflection. The border setting doesn't change the reflection in the object, it only changes what part of the image is rendered.

Rendering an image starts at the pixel that will be visible in the final image and sends a "ray" into the scene to determine what colour the specific pixel will be. Each ray will bounce around in the scene from object to object to light source based on render settings to calculate the final result. While the render border will reduce the pixels used as the starting point for each ray, it does not reduce the objects or lights in the scene that each ray may come into contact with. Each ray going through the scene will see every visible object and light in the scene that can influence the final result for each pixel.

[This conference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGqzbGAT6wQ) explains ray types and might give you a better grasp of how a ray goes through a scene to get the final image.

Comment: Thanks sambler, I know what border render do, I know how to use this feature. I would like to know how this feature is designed, what are mathematical aspects, how blender is able to compute exact pixel colouring withouth computing all the lights in the scene. I suppose that in order to compute rays for raytracing it starts from the border to render and he jumps from point to point in order to reach the source of the light, but since this light could be placed in a part of the scene not to render, how can blender compute the exact colouring? Do you have any reference?

Comment: Render border only limits the pixels of the final image it does not change any of the objects in the scene that are used to generate the final pixel colour.